# Covariance/heat flux in Python

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I'm looking to compute poleward heat fluxes at a level in the atmosphere, i.e the mean of (u't') . I'm aware of the covariance function in NumPy, but cannot seem to implement it. Here is my code below.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

myfile = '/home/ubuntu/Fluxes_Test/out.nc' 
Import = Dataset(myfile, mode='r')

lon   = Import.variables['lon'][:]   # Longitude
lat   = Import.variables['lat'][:]   # Latitude
time  = Import.variables['time'][:]  # Time
lev   = Import.variables['lev'][:]   # Level
wind  = Import.variables['ua'][:]
temp  = Import.variables['ta'][:]

lon = lon-180   # to shift co-ordinates to -180 to 180.

variable1 = np.squeeze(wind,temp, axis=0)
variable2 = np.cov(variable1)

m = Basemap(resolution='l')
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)

X, Y = m(lons, lats)
cs = m.pcolor(X,Y, variable2)
plt.show()
```

The shape of the variables wind and temp which I am trying to compute the flux of (the covariance) are both (3960,64,128), so 3960 pieces of data on a 64x128 grid (with co-ordinates).

I tried squeezing both variables to produce a array of (3960, 3960, 64,128) so cov could work on these first two series of data (the two 3960's) of wind and temp, but this didn't work.

Comment: Can you write out using Python loops exactly what value you are trying to compute? It would be helpful if you show a concrete example of what you want to happen with **small** `wind` and `temp` arrays.

Comment: If `windtemp` has shape (3960, 3960, 64, 128), what value should `windtemp[i,j,k,l]` hold? It seems it should depend on **both** `wind[i,k,l]` and `temp[j,k,l]`. How do you wish to combine them?

Comment: Also, it's not clear (at least to me) what `np.cov` is doing when passed a 4D array. Note that `np.cov(np.random.randn(3,2,4,2)).shape` is `(3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3)`. Is that really the shape of the array you want?

Comment: "I tried squeezing both variables to produce a array of (3960, 3960, 64,128)"  `np.squeeze` does not do what you (apparently) think it does.  Take another look at its docstring: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html

Comment: Thanks for all the replies so far. Essentially, imagine a 2d grid of boxes, where each box contains a temperature and wind for every day. I want to find the mean of the temperature of a box over the time series of data, minus each daily data from the mean to compute a fluctuation, same with wind. Its difficult to explain, so apologies!